# Using method with recoverWith

Tags: scala

I am trying to write generic recovery handler on service call as follow.

```
def handleServerResponse(payLoad: PayLoad): Future[WSResponse] = {
  payLoad.callType match {
    case postJson => broker.postJson(payLoad.url, payLoad.data, payLoad.hadler).recoverWith {
      //How to use recoverHandler?
    }
    case getJson => broker.getJson(payLoad.url, payLoad.mapper).recoverWith {
      //How to use recoverHandler?
    }
    case delete => broker.delete(payLoad.url).recoverWith {
      //How to use recoverHandler?
    }

  }
}

def recoverHandler(): Future[WSResponse] = {
  case ex: ForbiddenException =>
    Logger.error(s"Forbidden to access.  Not going to retry.", ex)
    Future.failed(new NoRetryException("foo", ex))
  case ex: Throwable =>
    Logger.error(s"Received error.  Will retry later.", ex)
    Future.failed(new RetryExternalException("foo", ex))
}
```

But I am not sure how to use recoverHandler() in above case. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recoverWith` method is expecting a partial function, so that is what you need to declare your handler method to be:

```
def recoverHandler(): PartialFunction[Throwable,Future[WSResponse]] = {
  case ex: ForbiddenException =>
    Logger.error(s"Forbidden to access.  Not going to retry.", ex)
    Future.failed(new NoRetryException("foo", ex))
  case ex: Throwable =>
    Logger.error(s"Received error.  Will retry later.", ex)
    Future.failed(new RetryExternalException("foo", ex))
}
```

Then, you can use it as simply as:

```
broker.delete(payLoad.url) recoverWith recoverHandler
```

or

```
broker.delete(payLoad.url).recoverWith(recoverHandler)
```